# Is it possible for a phone to send multiple requests when it has a bad network connection?

Tags: android, ios, networking, mobile

What exactly happens when I try to make a request on the phone when I lose network connection? Is it possible for the phone's os/sdk to send multiple requests when I only asked for one? Is it possible for a phone to make a burst of requests, all exactly the same?

Comment: It would help to update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

use filters to check Internet Status ( WIFI / MOBILE ( 2G,3G & 4G ) )

Code.........

```
 if(Contant_status.equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")){
                Log.v("haveNetworkConnection","WIFI");
            }else if(Contant_status.equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")){
                if(getNetworkClass(MainActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("2G")){
                    Log.v("haveNetworkConnection","2G");
                }else if(getNetworkClass(MainActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("3G")){
                    Log.v("haveNetworkConnection","3G");
                }else if(getNetworkClass(MainActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("4G")){
                    Log.v("haveNetworkConnection","4G");
                }else if(getNetworkClass(MainActivity.this).equalsIgnoreCase("Unknown")){
                    Log.v("haveNetworkConnection","Unknown");
                }
            }

  private void haveNetworkConnection() {
    String haveConnectedWifi = "";
    String haveConnectedMobile = "";

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = "WIFI";
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = "MOBILE";
    }
    if(haveConnectedWifi.equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")){
        Contant_status = "WIFI";
    }else if(haveConnectedMobile.equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")){
        Contant_status = "MOBILE";
    }
}

public String getNetworkClass(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}
```